# Новая строчка в textarea в базу денных

Tags: база-данных, php

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, мне нужно сделать такую вещь, у меня есть обычное поле textarea, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если в текстовом поле была новая строчка, например

```
Это первая строчка
А это вторая
```

То и выводился текст из базы в таком-же виде, а у меня всё выводит в одной строчке. Как быть? :(

Comment: вы видимо, не храните в базе перевод строки. http://jsfiddle.net/LU8pE/

Comment: у вас текст в базе должен храниться с символами разделения строки `\r\n`, если их нету, то и выводиться будет в строку. Это, если вы выводите текст из базы снова в textarea, если же выводите в html элемент, то `\r\n` надо заменить на `<br>`

Comment: А можно узнать, как эти \r\n вычислить в строчке? Или как их расставить в нужных местах? У меня при сохранении почему-то ничего подобного нету((

Comment: @Angus123, ответьте, вам выводить этот текст надо снова в textarea? Как вариант кладите в базу, заменив разрыв строки на <br>:

    $texttoBase = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $_POST['text']);
    // сохранение в базу

А когда достанете из базы, заменить обратно:

    // достали текст из базы
    $text = str_replace("<br>", "\n", $textFromDb);

Теперь можете выводить это в textarea, однако, если вы хотите вывести в какой-нибудь div или span и пр., то обратной конвертации, не надо

Comment: @Angus123, наверное, вы их как-то вырезаете. Стоит привести код записи в базу.

Comment: [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php)

А еще лучше (на мой, конечно, взгляд) пользоваться [markdown](https://github.com/cebe/markdown) и превращять все в параграфы. *br не нужен.*